# Auto size row in datagrid view

Tags: .net, datagridview

hai sir ,
     how to Increase height of the row in datagridview by automaticaly, when the text (character)  should wrap in the same row.Then the row height should be increase automaticaly. for example

```
---------- this is column width
column1

----------
abcdefghijklmn
----------
```

here "klmn" come next line. But we manualy increase the row height that will showing. but i want automaticaly increase the row height. what i do sir

Comment: What property will set the height of row in datagridview automatically? wrap mode is set to true

Answer (score 3):

There is a property `AutoSizeRowsMode`. Set it to `AllCells` or `DisplayedCells`. `AllCells` will take time if datagridview has very large number of rows. `DisplayedCells` will resize displayed cells only.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

Comment: OP asked for row height, not column width.

Answer (score 0):

height or width? - the normal in this cases is to have overflow: hidden; and ... or show the complete string in a tooltip or, when the user mouse hover the string, it will start run (horizontal scroll) the string to be full readable.

Is this what you're looking for?